# Extract value from a response and populate in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin and struggling with a basic issue. I have a function which returns me a Json response which contains few fields as :

```
{
    “PersonId”: 123,
    “PersonType”: [
        {
            “Age”: “10”,
            “Pid”: “ABC”
            “Ptype”: “abc”
        },
         {
            “Age”: “10”,
            “Pid”: “PQR”,
            “Ptype”: “per”
        }
    ]
}
```

I have another function which has a family object (a `List<<FamilyType>>`) and it makes a call to above function. So what I basically need to do is extract Pid from this response and populate the family object which has a field called “Pid”.

I am not sure how to extract the details and then populate it in Kotlin.

Comment: It would be better to add your code around the functions that you have, including the type of the "response" that you've mentioned.

Comment: The code is confidential so I cannot put that. But what I am wondering is that can it be done using some fancy lambda functions and stuff ? If yes, I am not sure how to. Also I cannot use nay third party jars.

Comment: The method call which returns the above reponse is somewhat like : `MyService.getPid(age, null)`

So may be if i can use stream or something. I am not sure. I have deliver this task by tomorrow and I am running low on time.

Comment: Please share your environment. Android? JVM? JS?

Comment: The environment is JVM

Answer (score 1):

Without third-party library:

On Android you have [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and can write (assuming you have your JSON as a `val json: String`)

```
JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("PersonType")[0].getString("Pid")
// returns "ABC" for the example JSON
```

(of course this is simplified, omits any error handling etc.).

Outside Android, JSON parsing isn't included in the Java standard library, but maybe [Java API for JSON Processing](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html) wouldn't count as third party for you as it's [specified by a JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353). Without this constraint I'd certainly use another library.

Of course, both of them are low-level and aren't going to let you just call `MyService.getPid` but instead you need to traverse JSON structure as in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options depending of your environment.

1.) On Android, the most common way is to use GSON, and if you are consuming a web endpoint, GSON + Retrofit:

Assuming you are on a JVM platform ( e.g. Android), you can use common Java libraries for parsing JSON, e.g. GSON. Here is a pretty good example: [Converting Kotlin Data class from Json](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-json-convert-data-class).

You need to first define a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), and use that to parse your JSON string:

val article = Gson().fromJson(json, Person::class.java).

Assuming your "function" is a http / restful endpoint, you can also use a library like Retrofit. If you are unfamiliar with Retrofit, it's probably worth checking out this example: [Retrofit Json parser](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/retrofit-android-example-json-parser-kotlin/).

Using Retrofit, the steps to solve your problem are:
1.) Define a Kotlin data class that matches what comes back from your function.
2.) Defining a Retrofit interface using that data class.
3.) Making the call to get the function using the interface.

Retrofit will then take care of the JSON parsing automatically. If the parsing works, you will have a object of the type of your Kotlin Data class, which will contain your data.

The above examples are for Android, but you can also use Gson and Retrofit in other configurations, provided it's a JVM environment.

2.) Another option is Kotlin X / Serialization:

Here is some code, taken from [an example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#quick-example) :

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class Data(val a: Int, val b: String = "42")

fun main() {
    val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
    val obj = json.parse(Data.serializer(), """{"a":42}""") // b is optional since it has default value
    println(obj) // Data(a=42, b="42")
}
```

You will have to add the dependency for kotlinx serialization:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.61"
}
```

( The code for defining the dependency may differ, depending on your setup, for more info, check out the example that I linked to.)

3.) Another option is to use [klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon), another JSON parsing library.

4.) On Android, [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader) are available ( See Alexey Romanov's answer, and gpuntos comment below).

5.) Without using a 3rd party depedency: You will have to implement your own parser.

Comment: Sorry but can it be done without using thrid party library. i am expecting something like a lambda function or something ? For eg. `MyService.getPid(age, null)`

This method call returns me the response as above.

Comment: this is not javascript, so such serialization is not included in by default in the language. Just use one of the provided libraries.

Comment: If you are on Android you could use [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader)

Comment: without a third party library , if you want to use JUST kotlin, you will have to write a parser, but that is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Or [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Thx guys, added links to these in the answer. Still holding that GSON + Retrofit is the most commonly used solution for this. Depends obviously on the use case / situation.